# Geofence event is not triggering without internet connection

Tags: android, api, geolocation, google-play-services, cordova-plugins

I am developing a login/logout app where employee enters to office & exit from office and I need to capture those employees IN/OUT transition. But it is working only when internet connection is on the device, not triggering in offline.

If I check the logcat output, the locations are keep on updating their. I don't know exactly why this is happening, may be location updates are coming from Google play services.

Below is the image with location updates in logcat:
[image]

I want to know that from where these updates are coming, so I can debug and fix.

Comment: Have a look, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46538931/8809599

Comment: @Sam. I am checking